# echo cutom css code to Wordpress page template file ? is this safe?

Tags: php, css, security, escaping

I created wordpress  page template and i want to add this css code only in to inside of this template only.for the security concern should i escape?. can anyone help me to solve this?. here is the code i used.

```
<?php  $style = "<style type='text/css'> .post-related {position: relative; width: 21.333%!important;} </style>";

echo  $style  ;
?>
```

Comment: If its hard coded by you and it will never accept data from unknown sources, go for it. there are better ways to do it but from a security point, if you control 100% of the code there is no problem

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the help.. really appreciate it.!  quick question can i put direct <style> </style>  without echo? in template? .. jut for knowledge .. thank you..

Comment: Sure, just don't put it inside the <?php ... ?> tag. I can post an answer if you like so you can have a visual idea of how to do it, only if you need =]

Comment: Thank you very much.. yes if you can it would be great..!  im new to WordPress template files.  thank you ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic template

I created a file named `about.php` in a pages folder in the root of my theme with this code.

You can do the same or change the location as you see fit, just dont put it inside a child folder that is in a child folder, wordpress can't read templates two levels deep it folder structure.

```
<?php defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

// Template name: About

// this gets the header.php file
get_header();
?>
<!-- Here we can do what ever we need -->
<style>
    .content .headline,
    .content .description {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .content .headline {
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .content .description {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>

<div class="content">
    <h1 class="headline">About Us</h1>
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur repellat eius a beatae consectetur, et perferendis impedit molestias itaque esse optio repellendus sapiente iure debitis suscipit temporibus voluptas architecto animi.</p>
</div>
<?php
// this gets the footer.php file
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Dear Buttered_Toast..thank you very much for the help..  now i understand everything.. this is very helpful for beginners..! Really appreciate your time and help..!

Comment: Great! glad I could help, I would suggest reading about wordpress themes/child themes and wordpress theme templates to get a better understanding of how wordpress handles all this logic, also check wordpress [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) to understand how to load js/css files the wordpress way

Comment: Sure I fill follow your instructions..! this is very helpful. again Thank you very much ..! :)

Comment: @Gayalcham Consider accepting this answer if you feel it helped you with your question =]

Comment: Sure i did it..thank you very much..!